# Does an ActiveRecord after_save call slow down the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

If I have something like this:

```
after_save :call_service

def call_service
  # call a super slow service
end
```

Will this slow down my controller (in the create action, where this model is being saved), or is this happening asyncronously? Is this true for `after_commit` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not happen asynchronously unless you specifically use a queue like [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) or [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) or some other background job processing alternative.

Comment: yeah i'm using Resque, but I am wondering whether it's better to call those queues from the controllers or in the active record hooks? i've heard some arguments for keep them in controllers is more readable. i might also break the hooks out into observers.

Comment: @botbot I would suggest triggering the job from the controller too and calling `save!` from inside the job, but that's more of a design decision and it depends on what you're building :)

Comment: you will calle save! inside the job and not in the controller action? what's the reasone for that? seem like you wouldn't be able to respond correctly in the controller. these jobs need to happen after the save action. so for example, if @mymodel.save then i'll run the queue. so you won't save the model in the create call itself? i've decided to place the resque jobs in the after_commit hooks, to keep the controllers light.